# remove child from hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do you remove a child from a hasMany relationship without deleting the child?

I have tried setting the foreign_key of the child to null. I have also tried using removeObject on the parent relationship.

here is an example.

```
App.Invoice = DS.Model.extend
  lines: DS.hasMany('App.Line')

App.Line = DS.Model.extend
  invoice: DS.belongsTo('App.Invoice')

App.InvoiceController = Ember.Controller.extend
  removeLine: (line) ->
    @get('content.lines').removeObject(line)
    line.set('invoice', null)
    @get('store').commit()

App.InvoiceEditView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'invoice'

App.LineView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'tr'
  templateName: 'line'


#invoice template
<table>
    {{#each content.tasks}}
      {{view App.LineView}}
    {{/each}}
</table>

#line template
<td><a {{action "removeLine" view.context}}>remove</a></td>
<td>{{description}}</td>
<td>{{price}}</td>
<td>{{price}}</td>
```

I am currently using

```
jquery 1.8.2
ember.js v1.0.pre-4
ember-data v11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that setting invoice to an empty string works.

```
 App.InvoiceController = Ember.Controller.extend
   removeLine: (line) ->
     @get('content.lines').removeObject(line)
     line.set('invoice', '')
     @get('store').commit()
```

Comment: `removeObject` did it for me to delete that one entry from the hasMany relationship

Answer (score 2):

In the `remove()` function, it `commit()`'s and then calls `remove()` again. That would cause the "setProperty in state rootState.loaded.updated.inFlight" error, because the record cannot be changed while the Ajax request is **inflight**.

If your intention is to actually delete the **Line**, thereby removing it from the **hasMany** association, then I suggest a `remove()` function like:

```
remove: function(event) {
  var item = event.context;
  if (item.get('isDeleted')) return;
  item.deleteRecord();
  App.store.commit();
  return item;
}
```

Note that once something has be marked for deletion by `deleteRecord()`, it will remain live in Ember with `isDeleted` == true until a `commit()` completes successfully. You may want to add a `classNames` binding to hide it with CSS once it's marked for deletion:

```
#line template
<tr {{bindAttr class="isDeleted"}}>
  <td><a {{action "removeLine" target="view"}}>remove</a></td>
  <td>{{description}}</td>
  <td>{{price}}</td>
  <td>{{price}}</td>
</tr>
```

With CSS like:

```
.is-deleted { display: none; }
```

Comment: mars thanks for the reply. I had a typo the remove() function should be removeLine() that then calls remove() which inherits from Ember.View and removes the element from the DOM. I screwed up when paraphrasing my question. But the problem is still the same. I need to remove the line from the invoice without deleting the line. I thought it would be easy to remove the foreign_key from the child or use the removeObject function on the collection but I get that error and it doesn't send the changes to the server on commit().